# Probability current density and Hamiltonian commutator in 2nd quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization

If the current density operator is
$$
\hat j(r) = \frac{1}{2i} [ \hat\psi^\dagger(r)\nabla\hat\psi(r) - \nabla\hat\psi^\dagger(r)\hat\psi(r)]
$$
then how does it follow that
$$
\langle \Psi(t) | [\hat j(r), \hat v(r,t)] | \Psi(t) \rangle = in(r,t) \nabla v(r,t),
$$
where $v(r,t)$ is some scalar potential and $n$ is the density? I'm trying to understand the equation following Eq. (5) in PRL **52**, 997 (1984) (seminal paper of time-dependent DFT).

**EDIT:** The potential is expressed as $\hat v(r,t) = v(r,t)\hat\psi^\dagger(r)\hat\psi(r)$. $n$ is the probability density, which is the expectation value of $\hat\psi^\dagger\hat\psi$.

Comment: This question is lacking context. What kind of state is $\Psi(t)$? What is $n$, exactly? How can $v(r,t)$ be an operator on the l.h.s. and its derivative apparently a number on the r.h.s.?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Indeed $v$ should be an operator on the l.h.s. $\Psi(t)$ is the state of the system at time $t$. I think this is actually not important and we can consider just the ground state $\Psi_0$ here.

Comment: To start with a more simple question, what is the commutator of a probability current density and the Hamiltonian?